# How to associate software with a specific link in the browser

Tags: vlc-media-player, chromium

I have a certain website that includes movies on streaming, and always copies the link and infects the VLC.
Is it possible for the browser to automatically offer me to open the link on VLC?
As I open Telegram links jumps the
[next post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd6J4.png)